# Installation of a python package via setup.py

Tags: python

I have made a bug fix in a popular python package `fastparquet` https://github.com/dask/fastparquet and attempting to try it out on my machine. The package comes with a `setup.py` and so I have attempted to use that to `install`:

```
fastparquet $ python setup.py install
```

This completed and appears to have done the requisite installation of files to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
..

Adding python-dateutil 2.6.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for fastparquet==0.1.0
```

However when we examine that location - specifically for the `api.py` file that was updated - it is still the original github version:

```
11:35:38/fastparquet $ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py

-rw-r--r--  1 sboesch  admin  27294 Jun 19 17:18 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fastparquet/api.py
```

After having looked a bit into `setup.py` it seems that were a standard approach used across most python packages:  https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html.

So then 
am I misunderstanding how the `install` works /what it does?

Comment: Did you change the version number?

Comment: @fenceop The only change made was a tiny one to `api.py`

Comment: @javadba Dumb question, but did you checkout the right branch?

Comment: @Coldspeed .  The question here is actually branch agnostic: why is the change I made not being published to the `site-packages`?  If I had checked out an incorrect branch then there should still (to my understanding)  be an *updated version* (of the wrong logic ..)  of `api.py` copied to `site-packages` . In any case I am on `head` which is the desired branch.